# Shorter MFA window per policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am looking to design an MFA policy in B2C that has a longer refresh token window (let's say 1 day) to avoid frequent MFA challenges, but have an elevated access portion of the application that requires more frequent MFA challenges because of the nature of the operations.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow, it appears I can accomplish this by creating 2 B2C custom policies with different refresh token timeouts and set the session behavior to **Policy**.

> ***Policy** - This setting allows you to maintain a user session exclusively for a user flow, independent of the applications using it. For example, if the user has already signed in and completed a multi-factor authentication (MFA) step, the user can be given access to higher-security parts of multiple applications, as long as the session tied to the user flow doesn't expire.*

**My questions:**

1. Is this the appropriate design to accomplish the goal or is there a more preferred approach?
2. Will this result in a user being double-MFA'd if they log in after 2 days of inactivity and immediately navigate to the elevated portion of the application? I think the answer is 'Yes', but want to confirm. Is there a way to avoid this double-MFA and have the policy recognize that an MFA was already triggered within its own window?

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting **Single sign-on configuration** to **Application** and use the same with your 2 custom policies. This will allow the user SSO to be shared for any policy being used and should allow session expire time to be controlled by each one of them. Also, if user has passed MFA authentication it should not need to do it again.